# SSL handshake error when use SSL tunneling via apache2.2?

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, proxy, ssl

i'm testing a ssl tunneling proxy on my local computer and my company uses a proxy to access the public internet.
which means, Client(curl, local) -> Proxy1(apache2.2, ssl tunneling) -> ProxyAgent(127.0.0.1:mmmm, local) <-> Proxy2(yy.yy.yy.yy:aaaa) -> public internet

Here is my apache settings(virualhost).

---

```
Listen local.ip.address:5000
NameVirtualHost local.ip.address:5000

<VirtualHost *:5000>

    ServerName test-server:5000
    ProxyRequests On
    AllowCONNECT 443

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:mmmm/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:mmmm/

    CustomLog logs/internalproxy_access_log combined
    ErrorLog logs/internalproxy_error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

---

i use this command to test:

curl -v https://www.google.com -U username:password -x http://local.ip.address:5000

the response is like:

```
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x989e70)

*   Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x989e70)
* Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx (xx.xx.xx.xx) port 5000 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to www.google.com:443
* Proxy auth using Basic with user 'xxxxxx'
> CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.google.com:443
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>

* error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

the correct response is like:

```
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: M:\tools\curl\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google LLC; CN=www.google.co
m
*  start date: Jan 23 09:15:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 17 09:15:00 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.google.com" matched cert's "www.google.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=Google Internet Authority G3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
```

Is there any wrong places with my settings?

Thank you!